# Read all available data in serial port with boost asio

Tags: boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I cannot find a way to make what seems to be one of the simplest thing with the boost asio library :

> Read all the data available in a serial port

For example in Qt there is a `readAll()` method from `QextSerialPort`.

Actually, all the examples I found are about reading a certain amount of data, or multi threaded.

In my case I need it to read the data from a GSM controller. The response size depends on the sent command and the controller context so I can't specify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
boost::asio::read(
    sock,
    boost::asio::buffer(buf),
    boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
    ec
);
```

Comment: It has been a long time since this question and I'm not able to test the suggested answer. Si if anyone has success with this, please tell me so that I can accept it.

Comment: I checked. Works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Oswin can you mark this answer? My code snippet https://onlinegdb.com/rkb5g-orwI it fails to compile online but work locally if standalone asio installed.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`transfer_all()` completion condition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_all.html) combined with the `read()` or `async_read()` free functions:

```
boost::array<char, 128> buf;
boost::system::error_code ec;
std::size_t n = boost::asio::read(
    sock, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
    boost::asio::transfer_all(), ec);
if (ec)
{
  // An error occurred.
}
else
{
  // n == 128
}
```

Comment: I just tried this solution but it seems to have the same behavior as the standard blocking read. In the given example from the official documentation they say : _Reading until a buffer is full_. This is actually not what I want. I need to read all the data **in the device buffer**.